# PID of last executed command is not being export nor saved

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am starting java process via command line: `java ...`. Let's call it `JAVA_COMMAND`. I am trying to run this java command with a start script in the background, and then save the PID to a variable so I can create a stop script that kills the process:

`my_app_start.sh`:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 directory=$HOME/apps/myApp/files
 current_date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%T")
 log_path="$HOME/apps/myApp/logs"
 log_file="$log_path/app_output_$current_date"
 err_file="$log_path/app_error_$current_date"

 nohup JAVA_COMMAND > $log_file & export MY_APP_PID=$!
```

Then I source the script, e.g.:

`start.sh`:

```
source ./my_app_start.sh
```

However, then when I check for `MY_APP_PID` with `echo $MY_APP_PID` it is empty. When I edit `my_app_start.sh` to:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 directory=$HOME/apps/myApp/files
 current_date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%T")
 log_path="$HOME/apps/myApp/logs"
 log_file="$log_path/app_output_$current_date"
 err_file="$log_path/app_error_$current_date"

 nohup JAVA_COMMAND > $log_file & MY_APP_PID=$! & echo $MY_APP_PID
```

it is also empty, however if I directly `echo $!` it outputs the process PID.

Why is this happening? Why is the exported variable empty?

Comment: last line should be `nohup JAVA_COMMAND > $log_file & (MY_APP_PID=$! ; echo $MY_APP_PID)`  (second `&` replaced by `;`, parenthesis) (You are forking 3 process, 2nd process set `MY_APP_PID` in parallel of third)

Comment: but the first command still doesnt work. without echo

Comment: @Archemar i tried to echo the value of variable to see why it isnt being exported.

Comment: In the first example, what happens when you substitute something else for `JAVA_COMMAND`, for example `sh -c 'for i in 1 2 3 4; do sleep 5; done'`? In the second example, you are creating two background processes with `&`, and `MY_APP_PID=$!` stores the PID of the first process (into a parameter `MY_APP_PID` _inside of the second backgrounded subprocess_, a shell executing the command `MY_APP_PID=$!`). Expectedly, that parameter is not visible to the parent process. Ref: [Asynchronous Lists](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What is the simplest version of the script that reproduces the error? Do you get the same behavior if you replace your script with just `sleep 5 & export MY_APP_PID=$!`, for example?